# MSMQ installation error on 2008 Server

Tags: installation, msmq

This Windows 2008 SP2

The Error:

Message Queuing: Installation failed
      Error: Attempt to install Message Queuing Server failed with error code 0x80070643. Fatal error during installation
   The following features were not installed:
   Message Queuing Services
      Message Queuing Server

Found a msdn blog with the following resolution:

Resolution

To resolve this issue follow the steps listed below:

1. Go to Control panel and click User Accounts
2. Select User Accounts and click Turn User Account Control on/ Off
3. Un-check the check box beside User Account Control
4. Close the User Account Window, reboot the computer  and try to install Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ) again

Note: Be sure to turn User Account Controll back on when the issue is resolved

After doing that and rebooting I still getting the same error when trying to  installing MSMQ.

Comment: You may have more luck with this at http://www.serverfault.com.

Comment: I have found a corrupt registry key that maybe preventing the installation. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSMQ it is throwing an error when selected within regedit: MSMQ cannot be opened. An error is preventing this key from being opened. Details: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Does any one know how to delete a corrupt register key?

Comment: You can use the regdellnull tool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897448.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility? http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/9/d/e9d80355-7ab4-45b8-80e8-983a48d5e1bd/msicuu2.exe

Answer (score 0):

create a key called MSMQ in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft` and then go and delete `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSMQ`. Worked for me on Windows 10 preview and then I was able to install MSMQ.